# Do ampersands work for user input in reports?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a working query that goes something like this:

Base table ACCT, link to others (listagg/subqueries) and ensure matching year("rollyear") field. Then the final step is to say which year ACCT table is in.

```
SELECT
FROM table ACCT
FULL OUTER JOIN table TABLE2 on ACCT.id = TABLE2.id and ACCT.rollyear= TABLE2.rollyear
...
FULL JOIN table TABLE7 on ACCT.id = TABLE7.id and ACCT.rollyear= TABLE7.rollyear

where ACCT.rollyear = extract (year from sysdate) +1
```

I typically use the calendar year plus one. I've been playing with using `ACCT.rollyear = &rollyear` to get user input... The limitation/issue I have is getting that running using the "User Defined Reports" feature.

Am I using this feature correctly? Does that only work for SQL Queries and not reports? Ive seen videos/comments about Stored Procedures and using "Accept...." but my attempts to mimic give errors and I'm not sure I'm on the right track. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query to use a bind variable:

```
where ACCT.rollyear = :rollyear
```

Then in the 'Binds' section you will see a variable with that name:

[image]

When you run your query you'll then be prompted to supply the value:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this is perfect!